# Baby names popularity program

Tags: c++

I have to write a program that allows the user to input a name from the keyboard. The program should then read from the file and search for matching name among the girls and boys. If a match is found it should output the rank of the name. The program should also indicate if there is no match.

Here is my program :

```
ifstream fin;
fin.open( "/Users/fashiontekk/Downloads/Assignment 3 Instructions/babyNames2017.dat" );



string nameInput;
string boyName;
string girlName;
int rank= 0;
int boyRank= 0;
int girlRank =0;

cout << " Which name would you like to check? < no space in names please > " << endl;
cin >> nameInput;

fin >> boyName;
fin >> girlName;
rank++;

cout << " After going through an extensive search here is what we found out - " << endl;

if (nameInput == boyName) {
    cout << nameInput << " is ranked " << rank << " in  popularity among boys. " << endl;
    boyRank = rank;
}
if (nameInput == girlName) {
    cout << nameInput << " is ranked " << rank << " in  popularity among girls. " << endl;
    girlRank = rank;
}
if (boyRank < 1 || boyRank > 1000) {
    cout << nameInput << " is not ranked among the top 1000 boys name. " << endl;
}
if (girlRank < 1 || girlRank > 1000) {
    cout << nameInput << " is not ranked among the top 1000 girls name. " << endl;
}

cout << " Hope that is the result you were looking for ... Ending program. " << endl;

fin.close();
return 0;
```

}

However, my output window says : Which name would you like to check? < no space in names please > 
Program ended with exit code: 0Liam
 After going through an extensive search here is what we found out - 
Liam is ranked 1 in  popularity among girls. 
Liam is not ranked among the top 1000 boys name. 
 Hope that is the result you were looking for ... Ending program.

I tried to type in Liam which the most popular boys name according to the file provided. I feel like my coding is right however I can't spot the error.

Comment: Hint: where is the file "babyNames2017.dat" ?

Comment: You need to provide the exact directory that it's in as well (e.g. `c:\babynames2017.dat`), or have it reside next to your program

Answer (score 1):

> It is my first year in Computer Science and I don't can't find my mistake.

OK, we've all been there at some point. You need to work on your debugging skills — you're gonna need them. In particular, spend some time learning to use `gdb` or whatever debugger you have available. A good debugger will let you step through a program a line at a time, watch variables, and generally checkout every possible thing that could be a problem.

So let's take a look at your code with an eye toward debugging it. It's handy that the message that's emitted comes right up near the top of the program — that really narrows down the places where you could be going wrong. Here's the first part of your program:

> ```
> ifstream fin;
> fin.open( "babyNames2017.dat" );
> if (!fin) {
>     cout << " File not processed ";
>     return 0;
> }
> ```

So, the first line just declares the variable for your input file. There's not much that can go wrong there. The next line opens the file... hmmm... I'm not sure if that might be a problem or not, so let's stick a pin in it for now and keep going. The next line, `if (!fin) {`, is a condition that only succeeds if `!fin` is true, which means that `fin` must evaluate to false to enter this block. And it clearly does enter this block, because that's the part of the code that emits the "File not processed" message. So `fin` must be 0, right? OK, so how can `fin` possibly be 0?

I don't have the C++ iostreams documentation handy, but you should go look up what that `fin.open(...)` call does if it fails. Given the way you've written the code, it looks very much like you'd expect failure to set `fin` to 0, right? So how can that call fail? Well, for starters, you're only supplying the file name... the working directory when you run the program might be set to something you don't expect, so the file isn't found. Or the file name might not match the name of the actual file. Remember that some file systems are case sensitive, and if you're working with such a file system then the `open` call will fail if the file is just named `babynames2017.dat` or `BabyNames2017.dat` or anything else that doesn't *exactly* match your file.

Comment: Thank you ! The program is running so far. I'm testing the name Liam which is ranked #1 on the list given by the teacher. However in my ouput it says : " Which name would you like to check? < no space in names please > 
Program ended with exit code: 0Liam
 After going through an extensive search here is what we found out - 
Liam is ranked 1 in  popularity among girls. 
Liam is not ranked among the top 1000 boys name. 
 Hope that is the result you were looking for ... Ending program.  " How come it's getting classified in the girls loop. I can't find the mistake.

Comment: @ForzaTekk It looks like you could benefit a lot from [rubber duck debugging](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rubber_duck_debugging). Explain to me what you think each line does in order, starting from `fin >> boyName;`. Also, please post a [mcve] including the full code, since the output you mentioned clearly isn't from the part of the program you posted. An MCVE also includes an example of what's in the file that you're reading.

Comment: @ForzaTekk Again, using a debugger to step through the program line by line will help you figure out where you're going wrong. What values do `boyName` and `girlName` get after you read them from the file? Given the output you've described, it sounds like the values of those variables aren't what you expect them to be.

Comment: @ForzaTekk You can edit your question to include the code. Rubber duck debugging is just a funny name for explaining the code line by line, out loud. You can explain it to your room mate, your teddy bear, whatever. The simple act of explaining out loud very often can help you realize where the problem is.

Comment: @FeiXiang It is the first i hear about rubber duck debugging. I posted an update in my previous question. Sorry I'm not fully aware about how stack overflow functions.

Comment: @Caleb I tried using it and it still makes sense to me. I cannot spot the error. I edited my previous post and include the code with the output. Any tips ?

Comment: @ForzaTekk Yes, look at the values of the variables I suggested. If you don't have a debugger you can print them out right after you assign values to them. Also, look at the contents of the data file and compare that to the values in the variables.

Comment: @ForzaTekk For starters, `fin >> boyName;` reads the first word in the file, and `fin >> girlName;` reads the second word. `rank++` adds one to `rank`, so it becomes 1 since it's initialized to 0.